# Animation Scaling?

Tags: c#, animation, unity, scale

I have an animation that changes the scale of the GameObject but also happens to change the position as well. I do not want the position to be changed by the animation, only the scale. How can I do that?

Comment: Is that gameObject a child of other?

Comment: @Hamza Hasan No.

Comment: Can you share some relevant code snippet and screenshot?

Comment: Depending on the object you can try to adjust your position-pivot accordingly. Probably at the bottom middle of the object.

Comment: I can say that there is not nearly enough information present to accurately answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the new scale to factor the new position!  (I just solved this for my game camera)

should be something like:

```
target.position.x = (target.width - target.width * target.scale.x) + target.position.x;
```

My code for re-positioning my stage (camera), centering on a target entity

```
stage.position.x = (- target.position.x * stage.scale.x) + renderer.width/2;
```